# Wrong class passed into class function

Tags: python, class

I am writing a program which has a `Settings` class that manage the settings in the program. There is a `SettingDialog` function in it that shows up the option window and a `lang_register` function that does some other things. However, when I call the `SettingDialog` function in the main window, it says that the class is a `ImageMenuItem` object and it has no attribute `lang_register`. But if I manually call the `SettingDialog` function manually and print its class, it says that it is a `Settings` class, which is what I expected. Can anyone tell me what's happening? The code is [here](https://github.com/Irides-Chromium/GUI-Encrypter/blob/master/GtkEncrypter.py). The error happens at line 110. Thanks very much.

***EDIT:*** I'll add some more details of my problem.

I add a line to the beginning of the `SettingDialog` function like this:

```
print(type(self))
```

so that it should output the type of the class of the function. When I try to access the option window in the GUI, thus calling the function, it outputs:

```
<class 'gi.repository.Gtk.ImageMenuItem'>
```

And error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./GtkEncrypter.py", line 110, in SettingDialog
    eng.connect("toggled", self.lang_register, self)
AttributeError: 'ImageMenuItem' object has no attribute 'lang_register'
```

This is rather curious because the header of the class is like:

```
class Settings():
```

and the GUI is built only in the `SettingDialog` function

---

Then, I try to call the function manually, so I add a line:

```
Set.SettingDialog()
```

after the

```
Set = Settings()
```

And so it outputs like this:

```
<class '__main__.Settings'>
```

I also checked my function definition, and the header is:

```
def lang_register(self, widget):
```

and the first argument is `self`, which should add the function into the class.

Comment: it's better to copy question related code here, other than give a total file for check. And also better to describe your question simple and clear, I think your origin question is difficult to check and answer, please think about it :)

Comment: Asking people to go through 350 lines of code to find your problem is a bit much.  If you can't simplify your question as @linpingta suggested, try more intermediate output before line 110.  Check the types of everything, and so on.  Be systematic.

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit and add something.